# Compressing and resizing images?

Tags: java, android, image, math, compression

For an android app I'm writing, I need to, through some combination of resizing and compressing, reduce the file size of large bitmaps to a specific threshold (e.g compress/resize a 2.3MB image below a 300KB). My current algorithm is just guess-and-check and is very labor intensive, time consuming, and imprecise. I was wondering if there is some sort of formula I can use to calculate how much resizing/compression is necessary to reduce the file size to below 300KB for example? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried [tinypng](https://tinypng.com) or [PNG CRUSH](https://pmt.sourceforge.io/pngcrush/)?

Comment: Sorry, should have specified, I'm writing an app that does this as part of its function.